# flutter canveskit image url how can convert to unit8list

Tags: flutter, xmlhttprequest

Error: ClientException: XMLHttpRequest error.,

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(getUrl);
  Uint8List byteTest = await http.readBytes(uri);

   http.Response response = await http.get(getUrl as Uri);
   Uint8List byteTest = response.bodyBytes;

   Uint8List byteTest =
       (await NetworkAssetBundle(Uri.parse(getUrl)).load(getUrl))
           .buffer
           .asUint8List();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. But I faced similar issues like this once and converting Uri.parse(url) to Uri.https(..), solved my XMLHttpRequest Error.

Example:

```
var uri = Uri.https('example.org', '/path', {'q': 'dart'});
print(uri); // https://example.org/path?q=dart
```

Check the following webpage for more info:

> https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri/Uri.https.html